# VS 2005 Quick Search Box Displaying Results Right Aligned (Windows 7)

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-7-x64

I have VS 2005 Team Edition SP1 installed on with Windows 7 Enterprise. I'm facing a weird problem which was not their with Windows XP.

Quick search box results are coming right aligned with scrollbar on the left. I have taken a screenshot. Not sure what exactly the problem is, any one?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCjy9.png

Answer (score 0):

This Windows Vista comparability installation solves the issue

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7524